# TFS2018 running NUnit / Selenium tests

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, tfs, nunit

I'm trying to configure TFS2018 to run my c#/selenium/specflow project for the first time. I have the job building fine, but I'm struggling with getting it to recognise my tests. Locally my tests are picked up and pass. I'm using NUnit, so I have NUnit and NUnit3 Test Adapter installed on the project in Visual Studio. At current in my build I have only a VSTest task, and this runs green but states no tests were found. Its looking for test assemblies with the following criteria by default:

***test*.dll
!**\obj**

I've done a lot of searching and I cant find anything that explicitly explains what I need to do to get TFS to recognise the NUnit tests. I see the 'path to custom test adapters', which I'm presuming needs to pick up the NUnit3TestAdapter, but I don't know how to point the task to that. Can anyone help me in laymans terms as to what step I am missing here? I'm fairly new to setting up jobs in TFS so any pointers would be much appreciated. There is a fair bit of material online, but what I've found all seems to refer to older versions and assumes a lot of knowledge!

Comment: Are you building the test project and restoring the appropriate packages, including the test adapter? Assuming the appropriate test adapter is referenced as a NuGet package and restored during build, VSTest should pick it up automatically.

Comment: Hi @DanielMann I'm not sure what you mean be 'restoring the appropriate packages, including the adapter'. I just have a build defined in TFS which is in the project where I host my code on TFS. If I go in to edit the build, I have a job of type Visual Studio Test, and a 'get sources' job. Where / how do I got about restoring the appropriate packages? The packages are obviously installed in my local VS project but not getting found in the build. Thanks in advance, Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`restoring the appropriate packages, including the adapter` what Daniel mentioned you should use the appropriate **Nuget Package** which include the test adapter NUnit and NUnit3 such as [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/) one in your project.

The easiest way to make this work is to add the NUnit Test Adapter NuGet package 2.x/3.x to your unit test project. The VsTest task should automatically detect test runners that are restored to the NuGet packages directory.

In the build pipeline add the [Nuget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/package/nuget?view=vsts) task to use the Package and restore during build.

You could take a look at this question: [How do I use NUnit in VSTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086874/how-do-i-use-nunit-in-vsts)

---

Another way(old) how to integrate NUnit Tests in TFS builds, this blog describes clearly how to do this: [Running NUnit Tests in a TFS 2015 Build vNext](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/03/16/running-nunit-tests-in-a-tfs-2015-build-vnext/)

> Simply summarized as follows:
>
> 1. Add Nuget Package for NUnit Test Adapter
> 2. Specify path of custom Test Adapter inside build definition
>
>    - Copying adapters inside Visual Studio TestWindows folder
>    - Specify Path to Custom Test Adapter with nunit packages

The blog OP also mentioned the new way in the comment, remove your test adapter locally in VS use Nuget Package instead:

> With the latest build engine it is enough to use the nuget package for
>   test adapter and the tests are run in the build without any problem.
>
> This is really better because the build will use the very same adapter
>   that you use in Visual Studio. The concept is, **remove the nunit test
>   adapter vsix addin from visual studio and instead add the adapter on
>   all nunit project as nuget package.** This should solve everything.

Comment: Brilliant, had just about worked this out but this is what I was missing, Many thanks.